# como obtener el valor de "border-color" de la clase ".ui-widget-header"?

Tags: jquery-ui

Estoy elaborando paginas web dinámicas y trabajo sobre todo con jQuery y php.

En jQuery esta el apartado de jQuery-ui que elabora una serie de themes que se pueden modificar dinamicamente. Pero hay algunas cosas que parecen bug. A continuación la explicación:

cambio el color del borde

```
$('.ui-widget-header').css('border-color','#FF0000');
```

y acto seguido intento ver el valor

```
console.log($('.ui-widget-header').css('border-color'));
```

y me devuelve `""`. ¿Me pueden decir la razón?

Comment: Si te cambia el color del borde?

Comment: cual es tu error exactamente?

Answer (score 0):

`$('.ui-widget-header')` te devuelve un array si es tu único elemento con esa clase puedes seleccionar tu primer elemento y luego extraer el atributo

```
$('.ui-widget-header[0]').css('border-color');
```

Answer (score 0):

tienes razon...`$('.ui-widget-header')` devuelve un array pero no es necesario estraer ningun elemento de ella para solucinar este problema. El problema es otro, cuando asignas un valor 
`$('.ui-widget-header').css('border-color','#FF0000');`
tambien se lo asignas a

`$('.ui-widget-header').css('border-top-color','#FF0000');`

`$('.ui-widget-header').css('border-right-color','#FF0000');`

`$('.ui-widget-header').css('border-bottom-color','#FF0000');`

`$('.ui-widget-header').css('border-left-color','#FF0000');`

y por lo tanto hay que extraer el valor por estos

`$('.ui-widget-header').css('border-top-color');`

`$('.ui-widget-header').css('border-right-color');`

`$('.ui-widget-header').css('border-bottom-color');`

`$('.ui-widget-header').css('border-left-color');`